# SSH Works For Some Hosts, Not For Others

Tags: linux, ssh

I've been having problems SSHing into my work computer from home. I have been able to succesfully ssh into one of our web servers so I know the ssh daemon is working and my connection is at least allowing some ssh. But when I try to ssh to my work computer it times out.

I went to my University yesterday and I was able to succesfully ssh into both the web server and my work computer. I've looked into our firewall at work to see if there are any blocks on my IP but it isn't blocked.

My ISP is comcast if that helps at all. I've done a few google searches and some comcast customers say that comcast sometimes blocks file sharing ports such as the ssh port (22).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try `ssh -v` .... It is more verbose so you would understand better the issues....

Comment: Here's what I got from verbosely running ssh...        OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to XXX port 22.
debug1: connect to address XXX port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host XXX port 22: Connection timed out

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 0):

First check the `/etc/hosts.deny` file of your work computer. That may contain lines which might suggests that certain IP may be blocked. Then check `/etc/hosts.allow` file. You can add your home-computers outgoing IP to your work computers `/etc/hosts.allow`.

NOTE: This question should belong to `superusers` or `serverfault`. `stackoverflow` is for questions that involves coding...

Comment: Thanks. I've never asked a questions on any of the sites before and had no idea where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

There is not one single "ssh daemon"... there is one running on each host to which you connect successfully.  If you cannot connect to a host there are two primary reasons:

1. There is no SSH daemon running on the host. In that case you will likely get "connection refused"
2. There is a firewall between you and the host, and it is not allowing port 22 to pass through.  In that case you will likely get timeouts.

If you are trying to connect to a host behind a firewall from "outside", as you suggest, it is extremely likely that host is not reachable from the Internet.  If the IP address of the "work computer" looks like `192.168.x.x` or `172.[16-31].x.x` or `10.x.x.x` then it is an unroutable private address and you will not be able to reach it from the outside no matter what you do unless a specific port-forwarding rule is set up on the firewall; in that case you would be connecting to the firewall's IP address, not your target host.

Comment: We do use a specific computer that the firewall port forwards any ssh requests to. Like I said in my initial post, I was able to ssh into work from the university internet connection I was using, just not from home. I'm also able to ssh into a different web server we have.

Comment: You're going to have to define what you mean by 'work' and 'university' networks.  Also any Internet-visible web server by definition has a routable IP address and if it's listening on port 22 can likely be reached by SSH.  It's the 'work' computer that may not be reachable.  Is 'work' on the 'university' network?

Comment: I apologize for not being very clear. These are 3 distinct networks with 3 distinct IPs - my home network being one, my work network being another, and the university being the last. Each network has it's own IP assigned by its ISP. My home has its own IP assigned by Comcast, my work has its own IP assigned by Comcast, and the university has its own IP assigned by unknown. I am able to connect to the university network and SSH into the work network via port 22 on the work network which is port forwarded to a computer on the work network.